# I need a terminal emulator that can change font size, have a background image, work with i3 and has no border

Tags: gratis, linux, terminal-emulator

I am currently using urxvt, which fulfills almost all of these requirements, except it doesn't allow me to change font size.

I need a terminal emulator with adjustable font size, in case I need to show something in a presentation or over skype for example.

I tried alacritty, which feels really smooth to type on and does allow changing off size, but it doesn't work that well.

Are there any other good terminal emulators, that allow me to dynamically change font size, set a background image, that is always screensize, meaning it doesn't get stretched when I use a tiling window manager and has no border so it fits seamless in i3?

I use manjaro i3, the emulator should be free and open source

Comment: What is your target Operating System? Linux? Price Range? Any Licence restrictions?

Comment: fixed the porst